# Handling netty AbortedException in Spring Boot / coRouter application

Tags: spring, netty, reactor-netty

I am building a Kotlin Spring Boot Application using coRouter to define routes.
From the frontend I'm sending Web Beacons and I assume some clients/webbrowsers directly close the connection after the data has been send. The question is how to handle the AbortedException thrown by the inbound channel closed.

The ApiRoutesConfiguration:

```
@Bean
fun routes() = coRouter {
   ...
   "/analytics".nest {
                POST("") {
                    onError<AbortedException> { _, _ -> awaitOk() } // didn't help
                    analyticsHanlder.persistUserActions(
                        userActionRequest = it.requiredBody()
                    )
                }
            }
   }
}
```

I get the following stack trace:

```
reactor.netty.channel.AbortedException: Connection has been closed
at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerOperations.onInboundClose(HttpServerOperations.java:615) ~[reactor-netty-http-1.0.24.jar!/:1.0.24]

Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
*__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.web.cors.reactive.CorsWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
*__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.AuthorizationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
*__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.ExceptionTranslationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
*__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.savedrequest.ServerRequestCacheWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
*__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.context.SecurityContextServerWebExchangeWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
*__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.context.ReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
*__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.header.HttpHeaderWriterWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
*__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity$ServerWebExchangeReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
*__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.WebFilterChainProxy [DefaultWebFilterChain]
*__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.reactive.server.MetricsWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
*__checkpoint ⇢ HTTP POST "/v1/analytics" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Original Stack Trace:
at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerOperations.onInboundClose(HttpServerOperations.java:615) ~[reactor-netty-http-1.0.24.jar!/:1.0.24]
at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelInactive(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:73) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.24.jar!/:1.0.24]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:305) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar!/:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:281) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar!/:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:274) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar!/:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelInactive(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:81) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar!/:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageAggregator.channelInactive(MessageAggregator.java:436) ~[netty-codec-4.1.84.Final.jar!/:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:305) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar!/:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:281) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar!/:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:274) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar!/:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:418) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar!/:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInputClosed(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:401) ~[netty-codec-4.1.84.Final.jar!/:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInactive(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:366) ~[netty-codec-4.1.84.Final.jar!/:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelInactive(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:221) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar!/:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:303) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar!/:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:281) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar!/:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:274) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar!/:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1405) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar!/:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:301) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar!/:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:281) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar!/:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:901) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar!/:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$7.run(AbstractChannel.java:813) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar!/:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174) ~[netty-common-4.1.84.Final.jar!/:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:167) ~[netty-common-4.1.84.Final.jar!/:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470) ~[netty-common-4.1.84.Final.jar!/:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:403) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.84.Final.jar!/:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.84.Final.jar!/:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.84.Final.jar!/:4.1.84.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.84.Final.jar!/:4.1.84.Final]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
```

Could someone guide me in the right direction?
I read creating a WebExceptionHandler might help.

```
@Component
@Order(-2) // is this still needed?
class ExceptionHandler : WebExceptionHandler {
    private val logger = KotlinLogging.logger {}

    override fun handle(exchange: ServerWebExchange, ex: Throwable): Mono<Void> {
        if(ex is AbortedException) logger.info(ex.message)
        else logger.error(ex.message)

        // redirect to default error handler
    }
}
```